# hiding url bar creating problem for popup window in webview of android

Tags: android

I have a simple web view in android. I am accessing some url. I have implemented WebViewClient which takes control from the default android browser, and overridden shouldOverrideUrlLoading. Now when i try to open a popup window, it opens that popup window (well not like a popup) in WebView, but the functions like close or submit doesnt work on that, even though the same thing work on the Android default browser. The problem now is that i want to hide the url bar and all icons like battery etc without implementing WebViewClient. Any one have some ideas?

public class Webcall extends Activity {

```
private WebView objWebView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    setContentView(R.layout.webxxml);

objWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        objWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        objWebView.loadUrl("url that have popup window " );//*check for any site having popup window the  popup window will not be able to call parent window*/
        objWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());

       }

 @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && objWebView.canGoBack()) {
        objWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: please do not close this question as you have done earlier because its  a issue which yet not been solved ,and it shows that we need to do some improvement in android.

Comment: There is `WebChromeClient.onCreateWindow`. It seem to address this, but I cant get it to work. Maybe you can take look at.

Comment: @nappy thanks for the support nappy ,this certainly  gives some hope  ,i am trying to use it as  replacement .